# How to disable back(parent) VC autorotate?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

```
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
viewController?.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After this block, on screen presented vc which have access to autorotate. But vc who present navVC autorotate too. How to resolve this bug?

Code AppDelegate:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    let presentedViewController = UIHelper.topViewController()

    if presentedViewController is FullOrientationRotate {
      print("presentedViewController is ", presentedViewController)
      return .all
    }
    return .portrait
  }
```

Comment: probably because you are using .overFullScreen that means the old screen is in the current context, so it will autorotate too

Comment: Yes, you right. I need to use . overFullScreen for transparent background on modal VC...